# How to get maximum value from sum of data in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to get the sum by considering each logtimestamp and need to get the maximum from that.

Here what I tried to get the sum of the dataset.

First I combine all three datasets from three different tables as below,

```
select 'user1' as user, 
       logtimestamp,Results 
from userT.table1 
where userID in (84161000) 
and userValue='X1' 
and date(logtimestamp)=date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day))  
union all  
select 'user2' as user,
       logtimestamp,
       Results 
from userT.table2 
where  userID in (84161000) 
and userValue='X2'  
and date(logtimestamp)=date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day))  
union all  
select 'user3' as user,
       logtimestamp,
       Results 
from userT.table3   
where userID in (84161000) 
and userValue='X3'   
and date(logtimestamp)=date(date_sub(now(), interval 1 day));
```

Then I have combine it as follows,

```
select logtimestamp,
       sum(Results) as TotalVal 
from ( **above Query**) b 
group by logtimestamp order by logtimestamp.

logtimestamp        | TotalVal 
--------------------+--------
2022-05-10 00:00:00 |  37114 
2022-05-10 00:15:00 |  29898 
2022-05-10 00:30:00 |  24090 
2022-05-10 00:45:00 |  19697 
2022-05-10 01:00:00 |  16296 
2022-05-10 01:15:00 |  13753 
2022-05-10 01:30:00 |  11727 
2022-05-10 01:45:00 |   9986 
2022-05-10 02:00:00 |   8798 
2022-05-10 02:15:00 |   7783 
2022-05-10 02:30:00 |   6925
```

Now I need to get the maximum with the respective logtimestamp as below.

```
logtimestamp        | MaxVal
```

I just tried to just get the max(TotalVal) but it gave me same results which I had before.
Can some one help me on that.

Update :
This is the dataset

```
userT.table1---user1 data
logtimestamp             UserID measValue   Results
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X1        12 //need to consider this
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X2        34
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X3        13
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X4        56


userT.table12---user2 data
logtimestamp             UserID measValue   Results
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X1        32
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X2        345//need to consider this
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X3        132
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X4        562

userT.table3--user3 data
logtimestamp             UserID measValue   Results
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X1        122
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X2        344
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X3        132//need to consider this
 2022-02-11 08:45:00    84161000    X4        561

Need the out puts as below,

logtimestamp              totalvalue
2022-02-11 08:45:00          12   
2022-02-11 08:45:00          345    
2022-02-11 08:45:00          132

Final output should be as follows,
logtimestamp              maxvalue
 
2022-02-11 08:45:00          345
```

Answer (score 0):

To get respective logtimestamp

One simple solution is You can get it by simply doing "**order by TotalVal desc limit 1**"

OR
it may become complex query like below

```
SELECT logtimestamp, TotalVal from (
   select logtimestamp,sum(Results) as TotalVal from ( **above Query**) b group by logtimestamp order by logtimestamp
) t 
where t.TotalVal in (SELECT Max(TotalVal) from (
  select logtimestamp,sum(Results) as TotalVal from ( **above Query**) b group by logtimestamp
))
```

Comment: didnt work that